# ZXing QR Scanning Animation

Tags: zxing, zxing.net

We're looking to achieve this animation with the dots below when scanning QR codes. We're developing the app in Xamarin Native. Does the ZXing team plan to add this kind of a feature in some of their future versions? Thanks!

[image: QR Scanning Animation]